# How to get the code in promise object success function to execute before the code after that call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have function named handleWidgetDrop . In the function I call another function insertBlankWidget which executes a certain function on return of promise object . The problem is that the code in handleWidgetDrop after the function call to insertBlankWidget is getting executed before the code in promise object. How do I undo this and execute the code in function after the promise object success to execute before the code after call to insertBlankWidget().

```html
handleWidgetDrop:function (){
    //some lines 
    this.insertBlankWidget();
    //Lines after insertBlankWidget call
}
  
insertBlankWidget:function(){
    var promise=this.getWidgetModel();
    promise.done(function(){
       //code which must be executed before Lines after insertBlankWidget
    });
}
```

Comment: Use a callback, http://jsbin.com/zejowogemi/1/edit ?

Comment: The trick is that you simply have to know which code is allowed to run asynchronously. Anything asynchronous has to go inside a callback function in JavaScript. Think of the callback as storing your code for later. Then, you simply pass your callback to a promise object, or invoke the callback within another callback, or use one of the many other available tools for managing asynchronous code execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chain a `.done` function on the promise. To do that though, you'll have to return the promise from `insertBlankWidget` :

```
insertBlankWidget:function(){
    var promise=this.getWidgetModel();
    promise.done(function(){
       //code which must be executed before Lines after insertBlankWidget
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Then you will be able to chain in `handleWidgetDrop`:

```
handleWidgetDrop:function (){
    //some lines 
    this.insertBlankWidget().done(function(){
        //Lines after insertBlankWidget call
    });
}
```

Comment: What will be the case if there is another promise object within the first one i.e nested promise objects??

Comment: @user3876636 Then return an array of promise and use `$.when.apply($, arr).done()`. It should work.

Comment: @user3876636 Do mean there's another promise within a `done` callback? In that case, you should replace `done` with `then` and at the end of the `then` callback, return the promise. This will produce a new promise that automatically flattens the inner promise for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what's known as a callback function.

Modify `insertBlankWIdget` so that it accepts a function as a parameter, and calls the function when the promise is complete.

```
insertBlankWidget:function( callback ){
    var promise=this.getWidgetModel();
    promise.done(function(){
       //code which must be executed before Lines after insertBlankWidget
       callback();
    });
}
```

then for `handleWidgetDrop`

```
handleWidgetDrop:function (){
    //some lines 
    this.insertBlankWidget(
        function()
        {
            //Lines after insertBlankWidget call
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: insertBlankWidget already has a parameter. In that case what should be done??

Comment: -1, sorry for this is an incorrect approach if OP is already using promises. You can just as easily `return` the promise. No need to re-implement this with a callback - not to mention it's ignoring errors.

Comment: It's cleaner to stick with promises since they're already available, but I upvoted since it's important for learners to see continuation-passing style, which is the foundation of promises and of every other JavaScript approach to asynchronous execution (until we get generators, which are still fairly similar to this approach).